# No "Team Foundation Content Manager" role in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

TFS best practices analyzer reports that my admin account does not have "Team Foundation Content Manager" permissions for the reporting services web site. When I browse to add this role assignment in the folder settings, it is not listed there.

How come it is not there, and how can I get it so I can set this?

It is TFS2012 on Win2k8. I'm investigating this because I get this error;
Cannot create a connection to data source 'TfsReportDS'.

When viewing the project dashboard. I'm not sure if it is related.

Thanks,

Tim.

Comment: Well, I added the role in Reporting Services SQL Server, and added the TFS admin account to the role. However, I don't know what tasks the role should be allowed to perform. I just checked all of them so far. I would very much appreciate a list of the tasks that should be checked if someone would be so kind.